# Highlight cell based on another cell's date -14

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

s I have a cell with a date R2, I would like to highlight all the other cell's in column R that are -14 days of the date in R2. What is the conditional formatting formula for that?

Comment: Do you want to highlight dates that are exactly 14 days before the date in `R12` or dates that are *within* 14 days of the date in `R12`?

Comment: All dates that are -14 or more than the date in R2 pretty much =$R<R2-14

Comment: That's pretty much your formula right there. `=R3+13<R$2` to be exact

Comment: You are a rock star thank you

Comment: So I thought it was working however I am getting cells highlighting that are only 5 days.. The date in R2 is 1/7/2019 and I have cells highlighting on dates 1/4/2019. I need "anycell in column R" < R2 "1/7/2019" Unfortunately I cannot just add the static date because this is a template sheet and the date in R2 will change. I also cannot use "today-14" other wise the historical spreadsheets will continue to update the formula.

Comment: Actually I think I got it just had to make a small change from =R3 to =R1 so the final is =R1+13<R$2